# how to: v-for and ajax

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have this section at a page where people can add more than one addresses. The user types the zip code and voilá, the magic happens. So far, so good.
But only for the very first one. The second one doesn't work.

Let´s see some code:

HTML part:

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                            <label for="cepPatrimonio">CEP</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cepPatrimonio" name="imoveis[][cep]"
                                v-model="imovel.cep" @keydown="$event.keyCode === 13 ? $event.preventDefault() : false"
                                v-mask="'#####-###'" @blur="pegaCepPatrimonio">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                            <label for="ruaPatrimonio">Rua / Avenida / etc.</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="imoveis[][rua]" v-model="imovel.rua">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="numero">Número</label><a href="#!" @click="addNovoImovel"><i
                                        class="fas fa-plus-circle float-right"></i></a>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="imoveis[][numero]"
                                    v-model="imovel.numero">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Loop markup:

```
<div v-for="(imovel, index) in imoveis">
<div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                                <label for="cepPatrimonio">CEP</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cepPatrimonio" name="imoveis[][cep]"
                                    v-model="imovel.cep"
                                    @keydown="$event.keyCode === 13 ? $event.preventDefault() : false"
                                    v-mask="'#####-###'" @blur="pegaCepPatrimonio">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label for="ruaPatrimonio">Rua / Avenida / etc.</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="imoveis[][rua]" v-model="imovel.rua">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="numero">Número</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="imoveis[][numero]"
                                        v-model="imovel.numero">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
</div>
```

The Vue method:

```
pegaCepPatrimonio() {
                const vm = this
                vm.isLoading = true
                axios.get('cep?c='+this.imovel.cep)
                .then(function (response) {
                    vm.imovel.bairro = response.data.bairro,
                    vm.imovel.complemento = response.data.complemento,
                    vm.imovel.cidade = response.data.localidade,
                    vm.imovel.rua = response.data.logradouro,
                    vm.imovel.UF = response.data.uf,
                    vm.isLoading = false
                });
            }
```

```js
var vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    imovel: {
      cep: '',
      rua: '',
      numero: '',
      complemento: '',
      bairro: '',
      cidade: '',
      UF: '',
    },
    imoveis: []
  },
  methods: {
    pegaCepPatrimonio() {
      const vm = this
      vm.isLoading = true
      axios.get('cep?c=' + this.imovel.cep)
        .then(function(response) {
          vm.imovel.bairro = response.data.bairro,
            vm.imovel.complemento = response.data.complemento,
            vm.imovel.cidade = response.data.localidade,
            vm.imovel.rua = response.data.logradouro,
            vm.imovel.UF = response.data.uf,
            vm.isLoading = false
        });
    },
    addNovoImovel: function() {
      this.imoveis.push(Vue.util.extend({}, this.imovel))
    },
    removeImovel: function(index) {
      Vue.delete(this.imoveis, index);
    },
    removeImoveis() {
      this.outrosImoveis = false
    },
    tenhoImoveis() {
      this.outrosImoveis = true
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" htrf="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      Tem outros imóveis em seu nome?<i class="fa fa-times float-right" @click="removeImoveis" style="cursor:pointer;"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
          <label for="cepPatrimonio">CEP</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cepPatrimonio" name="imoveis[][cep]" v-model="imovel.cep" @keydown="$event.keyCode === 13 ? $event.preventDefault() : false" @blur="pegaCepPatrimonio">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
          <label for="ruaPatrimonio">Rua / Avenida / etc.</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="imoveis[][rua]" v-model="imovel.rua">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="numero">Número</label><a href="#!" @click="addNovoImovel"><i
                                        class="fas fa-plus-circle float-right"></i></a>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="imoveis[][numero]" v-model="imovel.numero">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="complementoPatrimonio">Complemento</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="complementoPatrimonio" name="imoveis[][complemento]" v-model="imovel.complemento">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="bairroPatrimonio">Bairro</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bairroPatrimonio" name="imoveis[][bairro]" v-model="imovel.bairro">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cidadePatrimonio">Cidade</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cidadePatrimonio" name="imoveis[][cidade]" v-model="imovel.cidade">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="UFPatrimonio">UF</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="UFPatrimonio" name="imoveis[][UF]" v-model="imovel.UF">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div v-for="(imovel, index) in imoveis">
        <div class="divisor_laranja m-t-10 m-b-20" v-if="patrimonio_nao == false"></div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
            <label for="cepPatrimonio">CEP</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cepPatrimonio" name="imoveis[][cep]" v-model="imovel.cep" @keydown="$event.keyCode === 13 ? $event.preventDefault() : false" @blur="pegaCepPatrimonio">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label for="ruaPatrimonio">Rua / Avenida / etc.</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="imoveis[][rua]" v-model="imovel.rua">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="numero">Número</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="imoveis[][numero]" v-model="imovel.numero">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="complementoPatrimonio">Complemento</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="complementoPatrimonio" name="imoveis[][complemento]" v-model="imovel.complemento">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="bairroPatrimonio">Bairro</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bairroPatrimonio" name="imoveis[][bairro]" v-model="imovel.bairro">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="cidadePatrimonio">Cidade</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cidadePatrimonio" name="imoveis[][cidade]" v-model="imovel.cidade">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="UFPatrimonio">UF</label><a href="#!" v-on:click.prevent="removeImovel(index)"><i
                                            class="fas fa-trash-alt float-right"></i></a>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="UFPatrimonio" name="imoveis[][UF]" v-model="imovel.UF">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The response that I am waiting is something like:

```
"imoveis": [
{
"cep": "38406-392"
},
{
"rua": "Alameda City Campo"
},
{
"numero": "72"
},
{
"complemento": null
},
{
"bairro": "Mansões Aeroporto"
},
{
"cidade": "Uberlândia"
},
{
"UF": "MG"
},
{
"cep": "38406-000"
},
{
"rua": "Rua ddas FLores"
},
{
"numero": "511"
},
{
"complemento": "casa"
},
{
"bairro": "Florense"
},
{
"cidade": "São Paulo"
},
{
"UF": "SP"
}
],
```

I edit a snippet with a small part of my code so you can get the idea.
How to to that correctly?

Comment: Ideally your snippet would fake the server call so we can try it for ourselves. The question is a bit light on its descriptions of expected behaviour and actual behaviour: we have **the magic happens** and **The second one doesn't work**. Not clear what **first one** and **second one** mean in the context of the two sets of fields (one outside the loop, one inside). The likely problem is the `@blur="pegaCepPatrimonio"` inside the loop, which isn't passing any context to the method. Something like `@blur="pegaCepPatrimonio(imovel)"` might be closer to what you want.

Comment: Sorry if I didn´t make myself clear enough, @skirtle. I´ll try to improve my English grammar, promise. But I´ll try to pass (imovel) as You wrote and I´ll let You know.
Thanks!